# With Angular2 how to I have a child component update based on parent's property?

Tags: angular, redux

Given the components, similar to below... The parent's property updates fine, but the child never sees the changes.  What do I need to do to force the child to see the updates?

*angular2@2.0.0-beta.9*

`` //parent
@Component({
  ...,
  // child component in parent template set to pass property 
  // of [obj] as the component's obj property
  template: `
    Child doesn't update:
    <child [obj]="obj"></child>
    Interpreted output doesn't either
    {{obj.prop}}
  `
})
export class Parent {
  ...
  obj:Object = {original:true};
  constructor() {
    this._unsub = subscribeToExternalEventFeed(this.updateProp.bind(this));
  }
  updateProp(newObject) {
    console.log('parent change', newObject);
    this.obj = newObject;
  }
  ...
} ``

//child
@Component({
  ...
})
export class Child {
  @Input() obj:Object = {};
  ngOnChange() {
    console.log('child change');
  }
}

Comment: In this example I don't see you passing anything into the child.  So why would you expect it to update?

Comment: @DavidL the parent's template specifies [obj]="obj" on the child...

Comment: You did not originally have an @Input defined on your child.  I see you've added it now.

Comment: @DavidL yeah, I neglected that here, but that wasn't my problem, it seemed to be fixed when I changed the part of zone loading, and the reflect-metadata before zone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I wasn't loading the globals/polyfills correctly...

**BEFORE: Broken**
`import 'babel-polyfill';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'reflect-metadata';`

---

**AFTER: Working**
`import 'babel-polyfill';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-microtask';`